# Selecting a group of people

Tags: probability

> In 4 college faculties. Every faculty has 5 secretaries. Want to create a random group of 5 secretaries from the Secretariat college. No roles in the group.
>   Calculate the probabilities of all the faculty choose at least one secretary (A).

**I tried to think of it this way:**

$$P(A)= \frac{\binom{5}{1}^4 \binom{16}{1}}{\binom{20}{5}}$$

In other words, we chosen one from each faculty, so we have 16 secretaries, finally we'll take one more. 
Of course, the amount of the general options is to take 5 from 20.

According to the author of the question he chose the faculty, and he chose two secretaries and all the rest took one:

$$P(A)= \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2} \binom{5}{1}^3}{\binom{20}{5}}$$

I understand what they did. But I do not understand why I did not correct ...
Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 2):

You have counted each possible selection twice.  Let's see why.

Your term $\binom{5}{1}^4$ counts the number of ways of selecting one secretary from each of the four faculties.  You then select one more person, who may be on any of the four faculties.  Suppose secretaries $A$ and $B$ are chosen from the same faculty.  You have counted this selection twice, once when you select $A$ as the person selected from that faculty and $B$ as the additional person and once when you select $B$ as the person from that faculty and $A$ as the additional person.  Observe that 
$$2 \cdot \binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{1}^3 = \binom{5}{1}^4\binom{16}{1}$$

Comment: Really helped me! Thank you